# Constant Recieve TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I need to communicate with an old Java TCP server.
The way it works is that I need to establish a connection by sending a request, after the request
I am subscribed to events and the server sends me data through the connection so I need to
keep listening for data always. This is what I have and it works for some time but after a while it stops receiving.

```
            string logon = GetLogon();
            client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(logon);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            while (client.Connected)
            {
                byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
                this.ProcessMessage(message);
            }
```

I poll the server every minute in a seperate function to check if the connection is open and it always is even tho I dont get any data.

```
            bool poll = client.Client.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            bool data = (client.Client.Available == 0);
```

This works but after about 20 to 60 minutes I stop receiving from the server. Thank you for your help.

Comment: place the code in a separete method and when !client.Connected call the method again right after the while loop

Comment: This code is in a windows service and when !client.Connected returns false the service is restarted. But in my case !client.Connected is always true, I just stop receiving data.

Comment: Are you sure your'e not receiving data? How have you verified this? Does your code handle messages that get split into multiple receives? Does it handle two messages in a single received set of bytes, etc?

Comment: Yes, the server sends me "OK" after I establish a connection. and I do get other messages for some time. As you can see in the code I have a "ProcessMessage()" function.

Comment: From cmd.exe >Netstat -a to check status of the connection.  It is possible the server closed the connection and the connection is half open half close.  So see if Netstat give a TimeError.

Comment: @jdweng the connection is "ESTABLISHED". should it be "LISTENING"?

Comment: No.  A listener can have more than on client connected using the same port.  Netstat is grouped by port number and has one row for each client attached to the port.  When no clients are connected then you see LISTENING.  When the connection is established you cannot have a second connection with same 3 parameters 1) Source IP 2) Desintation IP 3) Port number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my polling mechanism was not keeping the connection alive.

First I tried this setting on the socket.

```
client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

And after that my polling mechanism started to detect the connection was down after some time but this only keeps the connection alive for 2 hours.

Then I stumbled upon this article which seems to do the trick. https://darchuk.net/2019/01/04/c-setting-socket-keep-alive/

Answer (score -1):

Try to surround your code with a try catch so you can see if there is any exceprion.
Another thing don't use client.connected becouse it changes his status only when you connect the first time not when the client disconnect so your loop condition will be always true.

Try this instead (just put your reading code into the loop):

```
// Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
do{
     numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

     myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
}
while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

[MSDN NetworkStream.DataAvailable FULL EXAMPLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Well I sort of need it to be always true, I have another method that runs every minute to check if connection is open and handle it if it is not, if you look at the second code block in the question. I have been running it for the last hour with a try block and no exception.

Comment: I added an if statement as you suggested around Read(). 
I tried sending data from the server 90 minutes after I started it and it was successful. 
I am going to wait a few more hours before marking your answer correct to see if it holds up.

Comment: I has to be ok.I've already used this solution and it was ok for me.

Answer (score -1):

I saw it but being connected does not mean that you have always data to read. You don't have any condition that verifies that there are available data to read. At least put an if statement in your loop to check the availability of the data.

Comment: That might be a good idea. But do you think it solves the problem of not receiving data after some time?